# Define the starting module in durandal 2.0 and navigate to it

Tags: durandal

It seems to me... that this way the initial route is defined via:

```
{ route: '', moduleId: 'viewmodels/customers', title: 'customers', nav: true },
```

When the application is loaded with the route `''` which must be oddly set to empty then this route is loaded initially.

When I navigate now to mysite/#/customers nothing is loaded.

How can I give my route a starting module which I can use to navigate to it?

In the old router I used startModule but I can not find it in durandal 2.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to setup a second route with the same `moduleId`. Here's a live example for child routes that uses this http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#hello and http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0

```js
define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/system', 'global', 'knockout'], function( router, system, global, ko ) {
    var childRouter = router.createChildRouter()
      .makeRelative({
          moduleId: 'hello',
          route: 'hello'
      }).map([
          {route: '', moduleId: 'default/index', title: 'Hello World', type: 'intro'},
          {route: 'default', moduleId: 'default/index', title: 'Hello World', type: 'intro', nav: true},
          {route: 'dFiddle', moduleId: 'dFiddle/index', title: 'Hello World', type: 'fiddle', nav: true}
      ]).buildNavigationModel();

    // .on is mixed in an not meant to be  chainable 
    childRouter.on('router:navigation:complete').then(global.createSampleLink);

    return {
        global: global,
        router: childRouter,
        getItemsByCategoryId: function( categoryId ) {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(childRouter.navigationModel(), function( route ) {
                return route.type === categoryId;
            });
        },
        binding: function() {
            system.log('Lifecycle : binding : hello/index');
            return { cacheViews: false }; //cancels view caching for this module, allowing the triggering of the detached callback
        }
    };
});
```

This specific setup that has child routes on all top routes use `router.guardRoute` in `shell.js` to handle the empty root case. There's an open ticket https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/issues/240 that discusses better handling of these kind of edge cases.

```js
define(['plugins/router'], function (router) {

    // Redirecting from / to first route
    router.guardRoute = function(routeInfo, params, instance){
        if (params.fragment === ''){
            return routeInfo.router.routes[0].hash;
        }
        return true;
    };

    return {
        router: router,
        activate: function () {
            router.map([
                { route: '', moduleId: 'hello/index', title: 'Hello World' },
                { route: 'hello*details', hash: '#hello', moduleId: 'hello/index', title: 'Hello World', nav: true },
                ...
            ]).buildNavigationModel();

            return router.activate();
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: About your 2nd code sample: My routeInfo.router object is always undefined when debug this code. But in order to return the hash I just did this: return params.config.hash; Thats the hash I have setup in the shell.js in the router.map array and it works :) Do you think that solution is ok?

Answer (score 4):

You can declare your routes like this:

```js
routes = [
{ route: ['welcome', ''], title: 'Welcome', moduleId: 'welcome', nav: true },
{ route: 'Visits', title: 'Visits', moduleId: 'Visits', nav: true },
{ route: 'VisitAddEdit', title: 'Add New Vsit', moduleId: 'VisitAddEdit', nav: true }
];
```

Notice how the `welcome` route is declared as an array (`['welcome', '']`) that includes an empty string in addition to a name.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best long-term solution, but my fix was to pass in a startUrl in the options object of router.activate() and then change one line of history.js (line 163, the end of the activate function):

```
return history.loadUrl(options.startUrl);
```

I call it like this after I set up the router mapping and buildNavigationModel:

```
router.activate({startUrl: 'hello'});
```

Hope that helps as a quick fix.

**EDIT**

To get the URL to update as well, I changed it to history.navigate(options.startUrl) instead of loadUrl.